# opencart 2.2.0.0 cart shows all the totals twice

Tags: opencart2.x

my issue is that when you add an item to the cart it shows the Sub-Total and Total twice for the Item thus making the total amount twice what it should be, even though there is only one item shown with the correct price.

this is a clean site no VQMOD or OCMOD I have imported some data from 1.5 however the products have all been updated everything else has been tested and is working as the store was created fresh only imported initial products and customer and order data.
if anyone can help it would be appreciated 
[image of the page and result in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s85S.jpg).

Comment: Is it showing in cart detail page also?
If yes then login to admin and go to Extensions >> Extensions >. Choose Order totals from the extension type and check if you have two order total active (Sometime updating code can make them).
If there is only one then need to check the code, hope code is repeating it.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I have checked this out and all looks ok, this problem occurred after importing the data so I am picking that there is something being imported to the database that is causing the issue.
I guess I will have to open them side by side and go through it until I find the anomaly.